# scalar field boundary condition in background with U(1) isometry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes

I have a simple question about [Lewkowycz and Maldacena's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4926v2)

In section 2, they consider the scalar field in BTZ background ground and require boundary condition of the scalar field,

$\phi \sim e^{i\tau}$ . This boudary condition breaks the U(1) isomentry of BTZ background. My question is what kinds of boudary condition will respect the U(1) isometry? phi does not depend on tau?